# Why can’t I see the manage nugets option?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am following this tutorial :

https://programmingblockchain.gitbooks.io/programmingblockchain/content/introduction/project_setup.html

I am using visual studio mac and stuck on this step

> Right click on “Dependencies” in Solution Explorer and select “Manage
>   NuGet Packages…”

I can't seem to find dependencies in solution explorer.

[image]

New to visual studio so please be kind :)

Comment: In short, Visual Studio and Visual Studio Mac aren't really the same product. However, there may be an option under "Add" given that it looks like it relates to NuGet packages...

Comment: Because your tutorial is for Visual Studio windows, not for the Mac.  They differ quite a bit.

Comment: You'll likely need to install NuGet separately. This [SuperUser question and answer](https://superuser.com/q/1166640) may help. There's also [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget).

Comment: I'll check my Mac in a bit, when the pinwheel of death goes away.

Comment: Thanks alot! @MikeMcCaughan (and everyone else). Turns out the tutorial is VERY old and not sure the nuget package is still been maintained because when I search for it , it doesnt come up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can I see the manage nugets option?

That because **the manage nugets option is active with project opening**. According to the your screenshot, there are only a solution file and a solution folder without any project in the solution or solution folder. So the option "`Update NuGet Packages`" "`Restore NuGet Packages`" are gray(unavailable) in your screenshot.

To resolve this issue, you should add a new project to your solution or solution folder, then double click(secondary click) on your project->**Add**->**Add NuGet Packages**...:

[image]

Or select project, under the option "Project", there are options "`Edit reference`", "`Add NuGet packages...`", "`update NuGet packages...`", "`Restore NuGet packages...`".

For some more detailed information, you can refer to following document:

[NuGet in Visual Studio for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/nuget-walkthrough#nuget-in-visual-studio-for-mac)

Hope this helps.